# Sign of $f(x)=−2 \sin(x)[\cos(x) + 1/2]$

Tags: trigonometry

According to my book f is positive on $[2\pi/3, \pi]$ and negative on $[0, 2\pi/3]$. Yet, I don't understand how we got to this conclusion. $\sin(x)$ is positive on $[0,\pi]$ while $\cos(x)$ is positive on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

I don't see from where we got $2\pi/3$.

Comment: The function $f(x) = -2\sin x[\cos x + 1/2]$ is nonnegative on $[2\pi/3, \pi]$.  It is positive on the interval $(2\pi/3, \pi)$.  At both endpoints of the interval $[2\pi/3, \pi]$, $f(x) = 0$ since $\cos x + 1/2 = 0$ at $x = 2\pi/3$ and $\sin x = 0$ at $x = \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly noted, $\sin(x)$ is positive on $(0, \pi)$. As far as the other factor is concerned, for $0 < x < \pi$:

$$\cos x+\frac 12 > 0 \Leftrightarrow \cos x > -\frac 12 \Leftrightarrow x < \arccos\left(-\frac 12\right) = \frac 23\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternate approach,
$$f(x) = -(\sin x + \sin 2x) = -2\sin\bigg(\frac{3x}{2}\bigg)\cos\bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)$$
For, $\sin x \gt 0, x \in (0, \pi)$. Hence, for above equation, $\sin\bigg(\dfrac{3x}{2}\bigg)\gt0,$ for $0 \lt \dfrac{3x}{2} \lt \pi $. Hence, $$0\lt x \lt \dfrac{2\pi}{3}$$ In this range, $$0 \lt \frac{x}{2} \lt \frac{\pi}{3}$$In this range, $\cos\bigg(\dfrac{x}{2}\bigg)$ is positive, hence overall equation is negative in $x \in \bigg(0, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}\bigg)$. Apply the same logic for getting the range in which $f(x)$ is positive. $\sin x$ is negative on $x \in \bigg(\pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}\bigg)$. Hence, $$\pi\lt \dfrac{3x}{2} \lt\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\lt x \lt\pi$$
$$\dfrac{\pi}{3}\lt \dfrac{x}{2} \lt\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$ In this range, $\cos \bigg(\dfrac{x}{2}\bigg) \gt 0$. Hence, we have, $f(x) = (-) \times (-) \times (+) = +$. Hence, positive in the mentioned range.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the unit circle in the plane.   $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1\} = \{(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) : -\pi < \theta \le \pi\}$.

Where is $\sin \theta = 0$? [Where does the line $y=0$ intersect the circle?] Answer: $\theta = 0$ or $\theta =\pi$.  Obtained by looking at the picture.

Where is $\cos \theta = -\frac12$?  [Where does the line $x=-\frac12$ intersect the circle?] Answer:  $\theta = 2\pi/3$ or $\theta = -2\pi/3$.  Obtained by looking at the picture.

Now you draw it, and see what you think.